# How to debug 'Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL": found none'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-httpclient, angular-test

In my Angular app, I'm testing my service that uses the `HttpClient` just like the official documentation suggests:

https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

This is how my test case looks like:

```ts
it('myMethod() should correctly sent the http request', () => {
  const mockResultData = { result: 123 };

  service.myMethod(); // will trigger an http request using the httpClient

  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/some/path?param1=a&param2=b');

  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  req.flush(mockResultData);

  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

However the test fails with the following:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL:
>   /some/path?param1=a&param2=b", found none.

Now it's quite clear to me that the triggered request hasn't exactly the url `/some/path?param1=a&param2=b`, however **the error message does not mention which requests were found instead**.

How can I debug this and check what requests were actually found?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to run the same test without `expectOne`, so just triggering the http request with `service.myMethod()` and then calling `httpTestingController.verify()`:

```ts
it('myMethod() should correctly sent the http request', () => {
  const mockResultData = { result: 123 };

  service.myMethod(); // will trigger an http request using the httpClient

  // TEMPORARILY COMMENT THESE 3 LINES

  // const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/some/path?param1=a&param2=b');

  // expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  // req.flush(mockResultData);

  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

This way the method `httpTestingController.verify()` will check that there are no requests pending and will trigger an error otherwise. So because there is indeed a request pending, it will now error with:

> Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET /some/path?param2=b&param1=a

which is exactly what I needed: knowing what was the actual request.

So in my case the problem was in the parameters that were swapped (`param2=b` and `param1=a`). So I could finally fix my test case:

```ts
it('myMethod() should correctly sent the http request', () => {
  const mockResultData = { result: 123 };

  service.myMethod(); // will trigger an http request using the httpClient

  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/some/path?param2=b&param1=a'); // now the params are in the right order

  expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

  req.flush(mockResultData);

  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```